# How "download_slot" works within scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'v created a script in scrapy to parse the `author name` of different posts from it's landing page and then pass it to the `parse_page` method using `meta` keyword in order to print the `post content` along with the `author name` at the same time.

I've used ***download_slot*** within meta keyword which allegedly maskes the script run faster. Although it is not necessary to comply with the logic I tried to apply here, I would like to stick to it only to understand how ***download_slot*** works within any script and why. I searched a lot to know more about ***download_slot*** but I end up some links like [this one](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3585).

An example usage of `download_slot` (I'm not quite sure about it though):

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
import scrapy

class ConventionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping']

    def parse(self,response):
        for link in response.css('.summary'):
            name = link.css('.user-details a::text').extract_first()
            url = link.css('.question-hyperlink::attr(href)').extract_first()
            nurl = response.urljoin(url)
            yield Request(nurl,callback=self.parse_page,meta={'item':name,"download_slot":name})

    def parse_page(self,response):
        elem = response.meta.get("item")
        post = ' '.join([item for item in response.css("#question .post-text p::text").extract()])
        yield {'Name':elem,'Main_Content':post}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    })
    process.crawl(ConventionSpider)
    process.start()
```

The above script runs flawlessly.

> ***My question: how `download_slot` works within scrapy?***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start with the [Scrapy architecture](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow). When you create a `scrapy.Request`, the Scrapy engine passes the request to the downloader to fetch the content. The downloader puts incoming requests into slots which you can imagine as independent queues of requests. The queues are then polled and each individual request gets processed (the content gets downloaded).

Now, here's the crucial part. To determine into what slot to put the incoming request, downloader checks `request.meta` for `download_slot` key. If it's present, it puts the request into the slot with that name (and creates it if it doesn't yet exist). If the `download_slot` key is not present, it puts the request into the slot for the domain (more accurately, the hostname) the request's URL points to.

This explains why your script runs faster. You create multiple downloader slots because they are based on the author's name. If you did not, they would be put into the same slot based on the domain (which is always `stackoverflow.com`). Thus, you effectively increase the parallelism of downloading content.

This explanation is a little bit simplified but it should give you a picture of what's going on. You can check [the code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/92801850546121f2faf95fd21c923904fde35c28/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py#L125) yourself.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with all the context and details so anyone can answer.

Answer (score 3):

For example there is a some target website which allows to process only 1 request per 20 seconds and we need to parse/process 3000 webpages of products data from it.
Common spider with `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting to `20` - application will finish work in ~17 hours(`3000 pages * 20 seconds` download delay).

If you have aim to increase scraping speed without getting banned by website and you have for example 20 valid proxies You can uniformly allocate request urls to all your proxies using `proxy` and `download_slot` meta key and significally reduce application completion time

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
import scrapy

class ProxySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'proxy'
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/products/1','https://example.com/products/2','....']#list with 3000 products url
    proxies = [',,,'] #list wiht 20 proxies

    def start_requests(self):
        for index, url in start_urls:
            chosen_proxy = proxies(index % len(self.proxies)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse,
                          meta = {"proxy":chosen_proxy,"download_slot":chosen_proxy})

    def parse(self,response):
        ....
            yeild item
            #yield Request(deatails_url,
                           callback=self.parse_additional_details,
                           meta= 
                           {"download_slot":response.request.meta["download_slot"],
                            "proxy":response.request.meta["download_slot"]})



if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0','DOWNLOAD_DELAY':20, "COOKIES_ENABLED":False
    })
    process.crawl(ProxySpider)
    process.start()
```