# Scrapy custom DownloadMiddleware does not respect DOWNLOAD_DELAY

Tags: python, scrapy

I am currently working on my CustomDownloadMiddleware. This is mainly due to a certain need for control over downloading the webpage. My CustomDownloadMiddleware looks something as below

```py
class MySeleniumDownloadMiddleware:
    """Scrapy middleware handling the requests using selenium"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        """Initialize the middleware with the crawler settings"""

        driver = init_chromium(crawler.settings.get('SELENIUM_HOSTNAME'))
        login(driver, crawler.settings.get('MY_CREDENTIAL'))

        middleware = cls(driver=driver)

        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

        return middleware


    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        """Process a request using the selenium driver if applicable"""

        try:
            self.driver.get(request.url)
        except WebDriverException:
            self.driver = init_chromium(spider.settings.get('SELENIUM_HOSTNAME'))
            recover_cookie_to_driver(self.driver, self.cookies)
            self.driver.get(request.url)

        body = str.encode(self.driver.page_source)

        # Expose the driver via the "meta" attribute
        request.meta.update({'driver': self.driver})

        return HtmlResponse(
            self.driver.current_url,
            body=body,
            encoding='utf-8',
            request=request
        )


    def spider_closed(self):
        """Shutdown the driver when spider is closed"""
        try:
            self.driver.quit()
        except WebDriverException:
            pass
```

After opening an [issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4591) in github, I had found that the issue is that custom download middleware are required to handle the download delay by itself, and the [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860181/how-download-slot-works-within-scrapy) are by using [slot](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/92801850546121f2faf95fd21c923904fde35c28/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py#L125) that can be found in this file. However, I had fail to find any relevant example of the slot being used in the download middleware.

Also, it is worth to mention that my code are heavily inspired by [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium), and had found an [issue](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/issues/36) which provide a potential solution for download delay, however when I use `time.sleep(second)` solution, the pipeline and spider's `parse` function are not being processed concurrently, which I deem the solution not viable.

Is there a proper way of implementing `slot` into download middleware so it respect download delay, as well as it will not hinder the ability of both pipeline and scraping being processed concurrently? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found reason of this behaviour.
It looks like your request don't reach downloader methods where downloader related settings used (including `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`).

In general case (according to [scrapy achitecture](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow)) this things happens:

4. Downloader middlewares `process_request` modify request and - send request to Downloader.

   Downloader:
    assign request to downloader slot 
   executing request from step 4. (counting downloader related settings).
   Received response - > sending to `process_response` methods  (step 5 of [scrapy achitecture scheme](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow))
5. Downloader middlewares `process_request` - modify response and - send response to `engine`.

Your in your case behaviour will be different:

4. Downloader middlewares `process_request` send `Httpresponse` object to Downloader (not request)
    as result of `process_request` method of your middleware.
   Downloader:
    will not execute request - because it already received response from previous step. 
   It will immediately send response to `process_response` methdos.
    
   5.(the same as above) Downloader middlewares `process_request` - modify response and - send response to `engine`.

This behaviour coded in:

- DownloaderMiddlewareManager [`download`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/13215cfb7150313a3e741460fe8d5a36df59cc75/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py#L32-L44) method.
- Downloader [`fetch`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c33fd47a80a36f779e3422dcf3fb05c2ac037035/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py#L87-L94) method (where DownloaderMiddlewareManager.download called)

On current implementation of scrapy downloader - `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and some other downloader related settings will work only for non selenium requests.

Comment: Does it mean that should I have my own downloader?

Comment: @TonyNgWeiShyang Yes, and You also need to implement `twisted` compatible way to run selenium requests concurrently (it is not implemented `scrapy-selenium` github repo) and I can't ever imagine how to implement this.

Comment: I had this exact same problem and, as the OP finds, the issue is that using the DownloaderMiddleware to make requests should not be done (though it's possible, and you can individually mitigate specific issues, like delays via re-creating slots). Instead you should create a DownloadHandler (modeled after https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/92801850546121f2faf95fd21c923904fde35c28/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py) and configure using https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-handlers.

Comment: While the existing HTTP Handler is "`twisted` compatible", does a lot of complex stuff, and returns an async deferred object, your implementation needn't be so complicated. It can do a simple request and return the scrapy `Response` if you wrap the `download_request()` function with `@defers` from https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/92801850546121f2faf95fd21c923904fde35c28/scrapy/utils/decorators.py#L30. You'll likely lose a lot of performance because you're basically breaking async, but you can implement it just a few lines (without breaking things the Downloader implements for you).

Comment: @JamesS I can agree, for example `scrapy_playwright` package - integration of Playwright Headless browser lib to scrapy - implemented by custom downloader handler as You mentioned.
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright/blob/main/scrapy_playwright/handler.py

It is not something new. However that practice (custom downloader handler for headless browser requests) - didn't exist on May 2020 when I published this answer.